# Tomcat 7 - Spring 3.2.1 - OpenJPA No persistent class is specified in eager initialization mode

Tags: spring, tomcat, openjpa

I'm trying to get a simple web app called Debugger running under Tomcat 7 using Spring 3.2.1 and OpenJPA. I use Eclipse as the IDE and run Tomcat external to the IDE. I'm getting a error when the WAR is being deployed. This is the error message:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No persistent class is specified in eager initialization mode.
```

Here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
-->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.0">

  <persistence-unit name="applicationDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.InitializeEagerly" value="true"/>
        <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Is the error caused by not having any classes specified in this file?  I'm just trying to get a base application configuration setup so I'm not yet ready to place any classes in the persistence file.  Maybe you have to have at least one?

Comment: " I'm just trying to get a base application configuration setup so I'm not yet ready to place any classes in the persistence file." And I was hoping to get an insightful answer from someone that knows.

Comment: For any others running into this apparently you do have to have at least one class specified in the file. Then you can move on to the next issue of run time enhancement. :P

Answer (score 0):

Either list your persistent classes, or remove the `openjpa.InitializeEagerly` property.